# Blender - trying to install Sverchok addon Scipy package, but PIP is out of date and have ~WinError 5 Access denied

Tags: python, scipy, pip, blender

I am trying to add a new addon for Blender Sverchok - SciPy(with a view to use the 3D voronoi node).

I have tried installing using PIP, but I get the following:

```
    Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fe/ef/60d7ba03b5c442309ef42e7d69959f73aacccd0d86008362a681c4698e83/pip-21.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting setuptools
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9e/d4/b99a960314121a003e9f39c61dfde01a1010bb47661e193a7722f7f32d52/setuptools-54.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (785kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 788kB 3.3MB/s
Collecting wheel
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/65/63/39d04c74222770ed1589c0eaba06c05891801219272420b40311cd60c880/wheel-0.36.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip, setuptools, wheel
  Found existing installation: pip 19.2.3
    Uninstalling pip-19.2.3:
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\program files\\blender foundation\\blender 2.92\\2.92\\python\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-19.2.3.dist-info\\entry_points.txt'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 21.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I have python installed on my machine separately and have been able to update PIP to the latest version, but this seems to be a different python install that has come with blender.

As far as I know I can run a python script in blender via the 'text' area and clicking run. This does work, but have tried a few things such as https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56011/how-to-install-pip-for-blenders-bundled-python and https://b3d.interplanety.org/en/how-to-install-required-packages-to-the-blender-python-with-pip/

I think I am missing something because I just keep getting that same error message.

I see there is the option to use --user permission, I just don't really know where or how to use it. I have also seen that I can open a python console area in blender, so I tried the following, but it just came back with a syntax error so I'm sure I am either trying to run this in the wrong area, or just dont have the correct code

```
PYTHON INTERACTIVE CONSOLE 3.7.7 (default, Jun 13 2020, 11:11:23) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]

Builtin Modules:       bpy, bpy.data, bpy.ops, bpy.props, bpy.types, bpy.context, bpy.utils, bgl, blf, mathutils
Convenience Imports:   from mathutils import *; from math import *
Convenience Variables: C = bpy.context, D = bpy.data

>>> pip install --user --upgrade pip
  File "<blender_console>", line 1
    pip install --user --upgrade pip
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any help would be much apricated. Thanks in advance.

EDIT

screen shot of trying to use the admin cmd prompt

[image]

This is what is in the blender python folder

[image]

Comment: as i see, permission denied - RUN CMD as ADMIN.   

PIP cannot be run from blender as in cmd, so syntax error.   

from cmd can run:   

`<local blender directory python> -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: Hi, I have added a screen shot of what Command Prompt to my original question as it doesn't seem to work, what is it I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: not use <>, think more. <code> is convention for any user defined code

Comment: Hi, yeah that's what I tried on the first one, did I have it formatted incorrectly? Thanks for your help by the way, it is much appreciated!

Comment: c:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender2.92\2.92\python\bin\python3.7 -m pip install --upgrade pip

Answer (score 3):

You can temporarily grant write permissions for all users for the python folder under blender:

1. Using windows explorer navigate to the python directory under blender.
2. Right click on the folder and select properties.
3. Go to the sharing tab.
4. Press edit that has the shield icon next to it.
5. Select Users then clock on the check for Allow Write.
6. Select Apply.
7. You should then be able to install scipy (or any package via pip in blender)
8. Remove write permission. (I skipped this because I accept the security risk since I'm the only user of the system.)

[image]

Comment: Hi Thank you for your response, but I have changed the sharing permissions on the folder: "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.92\2.92\python" to have allow all users full permissions, but still get the same  < [WinError 5] Access is denied: > error.

Comment: @ChrisMason Are you sure it's the right version of blender? When you start blender what version number does it say on the splash dialog?

Comment: Yes it says 9.92.0 in the opening splash screen, I found another way to get scipy from my system installed python which I had no issues downloading scipy with. I just renamed the blender python directory, so the default system version was then being used and I can now use the 3D sverchok voronoi node with no issues. Thanks for your time